# Prestashop y safari

Tags: safari, prestashop1.7

tengo una tienda en línea que usa prestashop 1.7.6.5 en la mayoría de los navegadores se ve bien, pero en Safari no se logran ver algunas imágenes, unas si las carga pero otras no, la verdad no tengo idea de qué pueda ser, leí que suele ser que los nombre de las imágenes usan acentos o la letra ñ, pero ese no es mi caso ya que los nombres de las imágenes están bien ¿alguien tiene una idea? :c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando llegas a una de las pantallas que no se muestra bien, ¿has mirado en la consola del navegador (y en las peticiones) para ver si hay algún error?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo acabo de agregar unas imágenes de lo que me muestra en consola, no me aparece ningún error :c se me hace muy raro que algunas imágenes sí las muestre y otras no, solo ese navegador me esta causando conflicto :c

Comment: Revisa la pestaña red. Todos deben haber recibido respuesta HTTP 200 o 302

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo ya revisé la pestaña de red y las imágenes que faltan me las marca en rojo como en la imagen que adjunte, ¿sabes a qué se deba esto? o ¿cómo podría solucionarlo? :c